# Updating a table in confluence wiki using Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, wiki, confluence

I would like to use Jenkins to update specific cells in a table created in Wiki.
I see that i can use the "publish to confluence" plugin, but i am not sure how i can mark the place that i want to update. The plugin help is talking about token - what are those tokens?

Answer (score 3):

In the plugin, "tokens" are wiki text.  They can be hidden Confluence Macros or even visible text.  The macros work best because they are hidden from the normal reader.  I use raw text matches on our Confluence because our permissions don't allow those macros.  Either one works.

I should not that my experiences are with Confluence 3.x.  Confluence 4.x apparently changes a number of things that have an impact on how this plugin works.

The plugin's page has a comprehensive list with examples and differences between 3.x and 4.x:

[Confluence Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin)

Comment: How about confluence 5.0? any tutorials?

Comment: I can tell you what I tried and it did not work:  from this page [Autonumbering Rows and Auto-totalling Numeric Columns] (https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TBL/Autonumbering+Rows+and+Auto-totalling+Numeric+Columns) I published in Plain text the Wiki Markup Input.  What I got is plain text instead of the expected table.